# Do Android Security Measures Work on an Unlocked Bootloader?

Tags: android, forensics, data-recovery

Let's assume we have an Android device with:

- Unlocked bootloader
- Full Device Encryption
- Password lockscreen

Will Android security measures (FDE and password lock) still be able to prevent data exfiltration from physical possession of the device?

Comment: What stops an attacker from manipulating the bootloader and silently implenting a keylogger (that logs your FDE password)?

Comment: I'm asking. Is there anything that stops him?

Comment: The answer (I guess): https://android.stackexchange.com/a/36831

Comment: That was awesome. I'll have to double check that I can lock my BL on a stock recovery and still be able to flash images from within the system.